# Java JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog hot key

Tags: java, swing, shortcut, joptionpane

I am displaying a confirmation dialog in Java using JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog.  The dialog shows a Yes No confirmation to the user.  This is called as follows:

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(sessionObjects.getActiveComponent(), 
                 "Are you sure you want to exit?", "My App", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

The question is as this is a simple confirmation, can the user press <kbd>y</kbd> for yes and <kbd>n</kbd> for no?  At present the user has to click on the buttons?

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505525/setting-mnemonics-and-hot-keys-for-a-joptionpane-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have "hotkeys" (mnemonics) for the buttons: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for "Yes" and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for "No".

You can also hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle between them and <kbd>Space</kbd> to press.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I can live with this for now.

Comment: i don't believe mnemonics currently work for buttons a Mac.  (Java 10).  Even if you run ButtonDemo.java from the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), the alt key highlights the mnemonic visually, but does not work to actually "press" the button with the keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

There is another simpler possibility: you can press <kbd>alt</kbd> in a program and then release it in a same way:

```
public static void pressAlt(){
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManualDetection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public static void releaseAlt(){
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ManualDetection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

then when you call:

```
 pressAlt();
 int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(... bla bla bla ... 
                                                  ,JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
 releaseAlt();
```

the behavior is exactly the same, as you desired...

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can create your own JDialog that could do that.

Comment: I thought I might have to.  I think using Alt+Y as dogbane suggested will suffice for now.

Comment: @Andez, yes dogbane's solution should work fine, but if you need to just use y or n, then you will have to customize the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Stopping Automatic Dialog Closing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)